# Using HtmlAgillityPack how can get just data without HTML tags?

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I am beginning to use the Html Agility Pack to scrape a web page in C#.
I wrote this code to get data from a table tag (at the moment I put the results in a label).

My goal is to put the data into a `DataGridView`.

Anyway I want to proceed step by step, so my questions are two:

1. How can I get just data without the html tags?
2. How can I get data from two or more tags?

This is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string url = "http://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/sweden/allsvenskan/results/";
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(url);
        foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table"))
        {
            //node.Remove();

            outputLabel.Text += node.InnerText;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT1:** I changed `InnerHtml` with `InnerText`. Is it possible to get data also from inside tags? This is an example of html code:

```
<tr class="first-row">
    <td class="first-cell tl">
        <a href="../matchdetails.php?matchid=MaxATAKK" onclick="win(this.href, 560, 500, 0, 1); return false;">Gefle - Kalmar</a>
    </td>
    <td class="result">
        <a href="../matchdetails.php?matchid=MaxATAKK" onclick="win(this.href, 560, 500, 0, 1); return false;">4:2</a>
    </td>
    <td class="odds best-betrate" data-odd="3.53"></td>
    <td class="odds" data-odd="3.37"></td>
    <td class="odds" data-odd="2.04"></td>
    <td class="last-cell nobr date">18.07.2016</td>
</tr>
```

I need to get "data-odd" values...How can I do it?

Comment: Use node.InnerText ..

Comment: Ok, I do it. Can you see my edit? I should get data inside tags, especially "data-odd" values. Thanks

Comment: Hint/FYI: "Data inside tags" are called Attributes

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
 foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table/tr/td[@class='odds']"))
  {

    var odds = td.Attributes["data-odd"].Value

  }
```